# Maximizing a function defined using NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I have two functions `fn[x,y,z]` which is in integral form and I have another function `gn[x,y]` which is also in integral form included with `fn[x,y,z]` as well.

```
m1[x_] := (2 (x - 1))/x;
m2[x_, y_] := (x (2 - x y))/(2 (x - 1) y);

fn[x_, y_, z_]:=
     NIntegrate[E^(-(z/(t m1[x])) - t/m2[x, y])/(t m1[x] m2[x, y]), {t, 0, 1}] + 
     E^(-(1/m2[x, y]))/m1[x] - (E^(-(z/m1[x]) - 1/m2[x, y]) (-1 + E^(z/m1[x])))/m1[x];

gn[x_, y_] := y/2 NIntegrate[Log[1 + z] fn[x, y, z], {z, 0,\[Infinity]}];
```

I want to find `x` and `y` which maximize `gn[x,y]`. I tried following to calculate `x` and `y` but they did not give solutions as they are keep on running.

```
x /. {#2 & @@ NMaximize[{gn[x, y], 2 > x > 1,1 > y > 0}, {x, y}]}[[1, 1]];
y/. {#2 & @@ NMaximize[{gn[x, y], 2 > x > 1,1 > y > 0}, {x, y}]}[[1, 2]];
```

Can someone help me to find `x` and `y` which maximize `gn[x,y]` using an  alternative method?

Comment: The problem is that `NMaximize` evaluates your functions many times, and each evaluation takes a lot of time, because it involves a numerical integration. A possible solution is to pre-calculate `fn` on a grid of values, construct an `InterpolatingFunction` from these data, and run the maximization function on that.

Comment: I need to calculate `x` and `y ` till at least 4 decimal places, and then I may have huge grid. Thats why I am looking for any precise in-built function is available in mathematica. Further, I dont know how I can use interpolating function.

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) and its links address how to use a numerical function inside another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `WorkingPrecision -> 5` in the `gn` integral gives you a reasonable convergence time. At the expense of some more computation time you can check that methods `DifferentialEvolution` and `SimulatedAnnealing` both return the sme result given here up to four decimal places.

```
m1[x_] := 2 (x - 1)/x;
m2[x_, y_] := x (2 - x y)/(2 (x - 1) y);

fn[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  fn[x, y, z] = 
   NIntegrate[ E^(-(z/(t m1[x])) - t/m2[x, y])/(t m1[x] m2[x, y]), {t, 0, 1}] + 
    E^(-(1/m2[x, y]))/ m1[x] - (E^(-(z/m1[x]) - 1/m2[x, y]) (-1 + E^(z/m1[x])))/m1[x];

g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  g[x, y] = y/2 NIntegrate[Log[1 + z] fn[x, y, z], {z, 0, ∞},   WorkingPrecision -> 5];

(*The following plot is expensive to calculate, but you may omit it 
because it's done only for displaying *)
plot = Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 1.1, 2}, {y, .5, 1},   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[.5]}];

ac = {};
Dynamic@Show[ plot,
             Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], 
                        Table[{ColorData["SolarColors"][i/Length@ac], Opacity[.5], 
                                Point@ac[[i]]}, {i, Length@ac}]}]
  ]
NMaximize[{g[x, y], 2 > x > 1.1, 1 > y > 0.5}, {x, y}, 
 Method -> {"NelderMead"}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> (AppendTo[ac, {x, y, g[x, y]}])]

(* {0.13979, {x -> 1.61673, y -> 0.819674}}*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ belisarius, thanks for your great help !!! You code really helps my work, and will be an interesting technique for others. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is partly that `NIntegrate` calls a function that at the given point in time is not full numerical (the first expression in `fn`). A way around that is to define the functions in such a way that hey will only evaluate for purely numerical values:

```
Clear[m1, m2, fn, gn];
m1[x_?NumericQ] := (2 (x - 1))/x;
m2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (x (2 - x y))/(2 (x - 1) y);

fn[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
  E^(-(z/(t m1[x])) - t/m2[x, y])/(t m1[x] m2[x, y]), {t, 0, 1}] + 
  E^(-(1/m2[x, y]))/
  m1[x] - (E^(-(z/m1[x]) - 1/m2[x, y]) (-1 + E^(z/m1[x])))/m1[x];

gn[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  y/2 NIntegrate[Log[1 + z] fn[x, y, z], {z, 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

Still, the numerics are relatively heavy, so some simplification/approximation might be required.

Comment: @ Oliver Jennrich, thanks for your answer, and it helps for me. As  @belisarius mentioned, this may be work faster by setting `WorkingPrecision`.